# Destroyed and Detached fragment not Garbage collected / still exists

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a fragment that hosts a a ViewPager populated by a FragmentStatePager adapter. The child fragment consists of an a square ImageView the width of the phone's screen and TextView showing a user's name. The purpose of this fragment is to allow for swiping through a series of pictures, akin to a gallery app, and all photos are loaded by the Picasso Library.

Neither of this fragments have private View variables, and both have onDestroy and onDetach called after popping the backstack on which they are on. However, after using Eclispe's MAT, these fragments still exist consuming memory and I have no idea why.

The fields of PhotoParentFragment consist of these alone:

```
public class PhotoParentFragment extends BaseFragment
    implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,
    Observer<Integer> {

public static final String TAG = PhotoParentFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String PHOTO_LIST = "PHOTO_LIST";
private static final String CURRENT_PHOTO = "CURRENT_PHOTO";

private boolean isBucketListMenuAdded = false;

private static final int DELETE = 4;
private static final int ERROR = 5;

private int currentPhoto = 0;

private ArrayList<Photo> photos;

public static PhotoParentFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, int currentPhoto,
                                             ArrayList<Photo> photos) {
    PhotoParentFragment fragment = new PhotoParentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Utils.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    args.putInt(CURRENT_PHOTO, currentPhoto);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(PHOTO_LIST, photos);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

The fields of PhotoChild fragment consist of these alone:

```
public class PhotoChildFragment extends BaseFragment
    implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String TAG = PhotoChildFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String NUM_PHOTOS = "NUM_PHOTOS";
private static final String PHOTO = "PHOTO";

private int imageSize;

private int position;
private int numOfPhotos;
private Photo photo;
private boolean isPhotoOwner = false;

public static PhotoChildFragment newInstance(int position, int numPhotos, Photo photo) {
    PhotoChildFragment fragment = new PhotoChildFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Utils.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    args.putInt(NUM_PHOTOS, numPhotos);
    args.putParcelable(PHOTO, photo);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

In onCreateView for the parent I setup my ViewPager this way:

```
 final PhotoPagerAdapter photoPagerAdapter = new PhotoPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), photos.size());
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    photoPagerAdapter.setPhotos(photos);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(photoPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPhoto);
```

No static references are anywhere. Now, when I pop off the fragment from the back stack, despite onDetach and onDestroy being called for all fragments both parent and multiple children, the fragments still persist. Calling getSupportFragmentManager.getFragments.size() also shows that the parent fragment is gone.

However, MAT says otherwise. The screenshot I show is the result of me clicking a photo from a list and pressing back 4 times:

Ignore profilePhotoAdapter$ViewHolder and UserListAdapter$ViewHolder. They are from separate things.

[image: MAT Histogram]

Note how 4 parent fragments persist and 12 child fragments (4 * 3) persist. It's driving me mad really. Merging shortest paths to GC roots yield this, which isn't exactly helpful:

[image: Merge shortest path to GC root]

So please, if anyone has experienced this, please how did you fix it?

Finally both parent and Child have setOptionsMenu to true.